# Keeping app windows locked in place

Tags: osx-lion, desktop

Is there a way to "lock" windows in place? To clarify, I don't mean snap them in place like you have in Windows 7, but instead "freeze" the window size and location.

I'm often working with many windows at once (firefox, a pdf viewer, texmaker, etc.) and I have them all positioned just right so that I can view them all at once on my monitor(s).

The issue is that often I'll move one of the windows out of place by accidentally dragging or resizing a window (via mouse cursor), or I'll unintentionally hit one of keyboard shortcuts (for moving/positioning windows).

I'm running OSX 10.7.5 on a macbook pro.

Comment: There are keyboard shortcuts for moving windows? Are you sure you don't just need to disable some utility software?

Comment: Yeah, like in OSX you have Witch and for Microsoft Windows you have AutoHotkey. It's intentional, so I don't think the issue is utility software (unless you mean something else?).